# ldap query only returns one record

Tags: coldfusion, ldap

Need help with an ldap query, keep seeing this forum on my searches, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm using ColdFusion cfldap tag, but my queries keep returning just one record. I've tried all the cfoutput, cfloop, (around the output, not the query itself) cfdump tags that I can thing of, but nothing seems to work. I'm hoping the problem is with my query:

```
<cfldap action = "query"
         name="results" 
             attributes = "dn"             
         filter="(&(objectCategory=group)(name=#form.userid#*))" 
             start = "dc=hhsc,dc=org"        
         scope="SUBTREE"
             maxrows="99"
             server = ""
             username=""
             password=""
             sort="dn ASC"
         separator="," />
```

I'm trying to get a list of distribution groups that begin with the value I enter in the form field, but as mentioned, no matter what I do, it only returns the first record found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you get if you run the exact same query via some other LDAP client?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. In case it helps another noob like myself, create a variable using ValueList, the output the results of the variable.

Comment: If you use <cfoutput query="result">#dn#</cfoutput> you should get all the records. Without the query attribute it returns the one record.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I tried cfoutput like you suggested and was surprised when it didn't work. Probably missed something because I was sure that would work, works in other places. Sorry about the triple comment, hit the return key by mistake. Can't find where to delete them.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I tried cfoutput like you suggested and was surprised when it didn't work. Probably missed something because I was sure that would work, works in other places.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I tried cfoutput like you suggested and was surprised when it didn't work. Probably missed something because I was sure that would work, works in other places.

Comment: Not just cfoutput. You must use the "query" attribute to loop through and display all records in the query. Otherwise, CF just displays the value in the first record. That is by design.

Comment: Yes, included the query in the cfoutput tag. The other thing I did that I found interesting was in cfdump, I included recordCount, and that always came up as 1. Strange huh? Anyway, it's working with the list so it's on to the next item that will have me banging my head against the wall for a few days. Thanks again for the input.

Comment: (Edit) That seems unlikely, as what you are describing is exactly what would happen if you omitted the query attribute. However, we can only make guesses without seeing the actual code used - and a dump of the results.  (Always better to post your code than "describe" it ;-)

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this Leigh, you were right, I used the query in the cfoutput tag and it worked. I know I was using that in previous testing, but obviously I was missing something. Many thanks. I'm sure I'll be posting again as I move forward on this project.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, you may just want to delete this thread since it was ultimately a [simple typographical error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) rather than an LDAP problem.